# Configuring SNMP on remote server via MMC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, snmp

When I go to the properties of the SNMP Service on a Server 2008 R2 server, I see:

[image: Local SNMP Settings]

Which is what I expect to see. However, if I do the correct thing and connect from my Windows 7 machine (which has a full set of [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) installed), I see:

[image: Remote SNMP Settings]

which is to say, less than useful. Is there any way I can get the SNMP-specific tabs to display on a remote computer?

Comment: Have you tried waiting about 30 seconds, and then opening the SNMP service up again?  Worked for me.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - just tried leaving it for a few minutes and trying again, but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What HoplessN00b commented got me thinking - what if I installed the SNMP Service on my local machine:

[image]

And voila, this worked:

[image]